# Getting min. value from list where column name in string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 Tb_AgentRates objrates = db.Tb_AgentRates.Where(z => z.AgentId == objcity).OrderBy(z => z.Rates).Min();
```

I want min. value of rates. But problem is that `Rate Column` in `varchar` that's why it's not showing result.

Comment: is agentId a unique column ? i mean are there multiple records with same AgentID

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Min-Value means that this is actually a number which is stored as string. You should fix that by storing it as `int` (or whatever numeric type it is).

Until you've fixed the type issue you can use for example `int.Parse` or `decimal.Parse`:

```
 Tb_AgentRates objrates = db.Tb_AgentRates
    .Where(z => z.AgentId == objcity)
    .Min(z => decimal.Parse(z.Rates));
```

Comment: Showing error can not convert double to tb_agents List

Answer (score 0):

You cant parse directly in Linq expression itself. Instead you can use like this

```
var query = (from row in db.Tb_AgentRates.AsEnumerable()
                     where row.AgentId== objcity
                     let range = ParseInt32(row.Rates)
                     select range).ToList();
        var minValue = query.Min();
```

and you declare your method like this

```
public static int? ParseInt32(string str)
    {
        int result = 0;
        return Int32.Parse(str);
    }
```